# error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

When I try to compile the following C-code with a nested function:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    
    int five() {
        return 5;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d ", five());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I obtain the following error:
`error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' in C`

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 and its developer command line, so my compiler is **cl**.

When I compile the program with **gcc**, I get no error, so I suspect it's related to the compiler, but how?

Comment: nested functions are not standard - just saying.

Comment: ...meaning: move the function five() out of main() -- place it before main, or declare it before main and place it after.

Comment: *Clearly something is wrong with my compiler*  This is wrong 99.999% of the time.

Comment: *because there is no mistake in the program* Yes, there is a mistake.

Comment: You have not found a bug in the compiler; your code indeed has a mistake.  Standard C does not allow "nested" function definitions (you cannot define a function within a function).  You need to move the definition of `five` out of `main`.

Comment: I am so sorry for saying that! I really could not see the mistake, and it DID compile on onlinegdb, and using gcc, that is why I thought it was the compiler...

Comment: @mand gcc allows nested functions as an extension

Comment: @mand - GCC has several extensions available, including recognizing nested functions, that will confuse those just beginning to learn C.  I suggest that when using GCC for learning purposes, or for creating portable code, that those extensions that cause it to behave in non-standard ways be suppressed.

Comment: If you are learning programming, always compile gcc with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`. Then you get lots of warnings (good) and pure standard C, no extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler works "token" by "token". After `int main() {` it sees the tokens `int`, `five`, `(` and `)` which are part of a declaration of function five (returning `int` and accepting an unspecified, but fixed, number of arguments). This declaration is completed with the token `;` but the next available token is `{` which makes the whole thing invalid syntax.

TLDR: nested functions are illegal in C.

Comment: BTW: though legal inside other functions, function declarations/prototypes are usually provided outside other functions.

Comment: nope... if you want to provide the prototype and make it local to the function body.  I'm afraid then you have to use it local.  This is valid syntax since K&R 1st ed. and continues to be valid.  Local scope is your friend, don't overavoid it.

Comment: you have not understood me... I mean if you want the declaration of an external function _to be local to the body of the function only_ (because you want to be sure you use it only there and get a warning if you use it elsewhere in the same compilation unit) then you need to reduce the scope of the prototype declaration to a single function body (or even narrower)  I have seen that phrasing in much legacy code.

Comment: You're right @LuisColorado. A function declaration/prototype inside another function limits the scope to the function itself. It's legal but seldom used.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int five() {
        return 5;
    }
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d ", five());
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your post clearly contains a syntactically correct form of the program.  Do you think without explaining, that the asker of the question understands why yours is correct, and theirs is not?  (A sentence explaining the reason why yours is correct would increase the value of your answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Properly formatted, with some start-end comments for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int five()   /* Start of Function FIVE */
{
    return 5;
}            /* End of Function FIVE */



int main()   /* Start of MAIN */
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", five());
    }

    return 0;
}             /* End of MAIN */
```